# Windows Phone 8 - More than one Camera Lens Icon per app

Tags: c#, xaml, camera, windows-phone-8

I am implementing a Windows Phone 8 Camera Lens feature for one of my apps. I am following the below documentation from Nokia Dev.

[Camera Lens Nokia Dev documentation](http://www.developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/Extending_the_Windows_Phone_8_Camera_App_with_Lenses)

My WP8 application has two different camera view-finder flows using Camera API, I would like to present them both through Camera Lens feature.

I am just curious to know whether its possible to add more than one Camera Lens Icon per app (just like multiple secondary tiles).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, its not possible. As per the [Lens design guidelines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/design/jj662922%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) - it's not explicitly mentioned about usage of multiple icons but imperatively it talks about one gateway for each lens app (by providing 3 sizes of icons for different resolutions with predefined names).